# Need to extract String in between strings using REGEXEXTRACT() in Google Sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula, nsregularexpression

I have a string like this patern: `"abcd abcd | abcde | Degree SP | xyz abcd | abcd ABC"`

I need to extract `"Degree SP"` using regular expressions. How can I do that? The condition here are:

- string end with "SP "
- string start after last "|".

I'm trying the Google Sheet formula `REGEXEXTRACT(<input string>, "[\|\s].+SR[\s\|]")`
It returns `" | abcde | Degree SP "`. How can I restrict to extract from the last **"|"**?

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, does `Degree SP` really have `**` before and after it, I have done editing in your question to remove quotes to code tags, kindly do confirm OR edit your samples to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13 for notifying me about **, it was an error. I just edit the post and remove those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string `Degree SP` should be between pipes and a space:

```
\|\s([^\s|][^|]*SP)\s\|
```

- `\|\s` Match `|` and a whitespace char
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s|]` Match a single char other than a space or `|`
  - `[^|]*SP` Match optional chars other than `|` and match SP
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s\|` Match a whitespace char and `|`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iTGKBx/1/)

[image]

If only the pipe after `Degree SP` is mandatory:

```
([^\s|][^|]*SP)\s*\|
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dqyAE9/1)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird
Your solution is just awesome. It solved the problem. That saves a ton of my time.

I have another problem relating to this one.
String pattern is "<string>  | <tring> | <tring> | Word1 Word2 | <string> | <string>".
This case pattern is static till the target area "Word1 Word2". I tried with "^.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?([^\\|]\S+)" and get the "Word1".
But I need "Word2". And sometimes if this string has the only word.

Comment: @Swopno If you want to capture the last word between the pipes `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^[^|\n]*\|[^|\n]*\|[^|\n]*\|(?:\s*([^|\s]+))+")`  See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cahlfU/1)

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I also looking for the option (tick mark).

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
^.*?\s+\S+\s+\|\s+\S+\s+\|\s+([^\\|]*)\s+\|.*$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/C94ogj/1)

***OR*** you want to catch value between 2nd and 3rd occurrence of `|` which ends with `SP` string then try following regex:

```
^.*?\s+\S+\s+\|\s+\S+\s+\|\s+([^\\|]*SP)\s+\|.*$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/tW5I3J/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^.*?\s+\S+\s+  ##Matching from starting of value with a lazy match till 1st occurrence of spaces followed by 1 or more non-spaces followed by 1 or more spaces.
\|\s+\S+\s+\|  ##Matching |(literal) followed by spaces followed by 1 or more non-spaces followed by spaces with |(literal character) here.
\s+            ##Matching 1 or more spaces occurrences here.
([^\\|]*)      ##Creating 1 and only capturing group which has everything till next occurrence of | to get Degree SP value mentioned by OP in samples.
\s+\|.*$       ##Matching 1 or spaces followed by | till last of value/line.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the string pattern is vary depending on the situation. Occurrence of "|" very in different situations.

Actually, I need a solution that defines the position based on the string "SP |". Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Swopno, ok could you please try following regex once `\b(\S+\s+SP)\s+\|` and let me know if this helps you?